# Combine data from other reference tab to the main tab

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to see other options using query function to pull the data from the "Reference Tab" which is the Employee ID and sum the values (duplicates) My reference will be the date from the main data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPOTw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFF1n.png)

Other alternative formula

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.